# Strategy for Understanding Eclipse bundles and plug-ins / Escape from dependency hell

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, eclipse-rcp, windowbuilder

My background:

I'm a pretty advanced Eclipse user (since 2005):  IBM RSA, Europa, Ganymede,
(then a lovely couple years away developing on NetBeans platform),
and last year I inherited an Eclipse RCP application shortly before the developer left, built on top of Juno with 'e4 platform' using Windowbuilder to design components and dialogs out of SWT widget.

Mostly that has been pretty smooth.  Windowbuilder seems pretty fragile, breaking and requiring a restart or re-install of eclipse occasionally.
Worse on Windows, but it recently broke on my OSX and I decided to try with a fresh install.
In the past I successfully muddled through, google'd the errors, and through trial-and-error eventually made it through instructions that other have provided ("just these 3 easy steps").

I have installed Juno SR2, added the e4 tooling 'items', and my Eclipse product (Eclipse application) starts up.
Windowbuilder seemed to install.  It downloaded a bunch of 'things' (Eclipse doesn't even have a common name for what it is that  "update sites" have).  It said it needs to restart, and then restarted.  When I try to open a java class "written" with WindowBuilder, I get an error in Eclipse:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
```

So, maybe something didn't download properly or fully.  Nothing in 'About Eclipse' > 'Installation Details' > 'Installed Software' suggests what this might be from.  Maybe something else needs to be updated now?  or maybe an update will fix something that didn't complete?

But just checking for updates gives me an error (I didn't try to install!  I just checked for updates!  Even deselected all):

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse e4 Tools (Incubation) 0.12.0.v20130520-0735 (org.eclipse.e4.core.tools.feature.feature.group 0.12.0.v20130520-0735)
  Missing requirement: Editor3x 0.12.0.v20130411-1653 (org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.editor3x 0.12.0.v20130411-1653) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench 1.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse e4 Tools (Incubation) 0.12.0.v20130520-0735 (org.eclipse.e4.core.tools.feature.feature.group 0.12.0.v20130520-0735)
To: org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.editor3x [0.12.0.v20130411-1653]
```

I am looking for the general strategy of how to understand and solve this error.

How do I find "`org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench`" ?  Names like this do not appear in the "Add new software" search area, or Eclipse Marketplace, or updates (why do there have to be so many ways to search?).  Terms like "e4" or "model" are too generic (is it part of "eclipse modeling framework" or "EMF" ?).

Note that I am looking for a general solution strategy.
I state the question in terms of a specific (recurring) problem, and if you can help me there, great, but the "correct" answer will be the more general revealing of Eclipse secret knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the binary jar to your local eclipse `plugins` directory.
You can find it [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.e4.ui.model/workbench/0.10.1/).

Comment: How would I know to look there?  I never heard of grepcode before.  Is  0.10.1 bundle version 1.0.0 ?  Does this match these 0.12.0.* versions ? When I put in the md5, the only hit I get besides grepcode is some maven site with a -3.8.0.jar -- but I'm running 4.2 ??!  Is there any sense to it?